# Cannot run karate tests with CLI

Tags: karate

I'm not able to execute tests using the CLI.  The runner works.  I'm using version 0.9.5.RC5 with maven command:  " mvn test -f pom.xml exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=com.intuit.karate.cli.Main -Dexec.args='-d' -Dexec.classpathScope=test"

Here is the error:
ERROR com.intuit.karate - driver config / start failed: failed to construct class by name: karate-http.properties not found, aborting, options: {type=chrome, target=null}

I java karate-apache, karate-core and karate-junit4 as dependencies.  The java version is 13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't yet support Java > 12: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/develop#getting-started

EDIT: use Karate 1.0

Comment: Thank you.  Works on 8.

Comment: @peter What is the correct version of `karate-apache` and `karate-junit4` version for Java 11? Please do not point the documentation. I am unable to find it, that's why I asked here.

Comment: @ShashiRanjan `karate-apache` does not exist any more. you can find details in the release notes, which I will leave it to you to find

Comment: @PeterThomas Even I used `karate-core` inside my spring-boot project, Getting the same error. Actually, the same code runs in IDE but not inside the jar. Looks like karate is creating some file on the fly?

Comment: @ShashiRanjan I strongly recommend that you follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: I am not sure If that is an issue.

Comment: @ShashiRanjan there is a way to be sure